# Jquery strip unwanted tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML data.

Raw HTML Data:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="box">
        <span class="conf"><a href="" class="remove">Remove</a></span>
        <div class="view">
            <div class="demoContainer container-fluid">
                <div class="box">
                    <span class="conf"><a href="" class="remove">Remove</a></span>
                    <div class="view">
                        <div class="insideContainer container">
                            <div class="demoRow">
                                    <span class="conf"><a href="" class="remove">Remove</a></span>
                                    <div class="view">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <span class="conf"><a href="" class="remove">Remove</a></span>
                                                <div class="view">
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

And I need like this format:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="demoContainer container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try jquery's [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) methods, but not the solution. 
How can I strip unwanted tags into raw html data? (.box, .conf,.view etc.)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9pw5cg6/3/)

Comment: @MoeThis is just .empty .box. I need strip all unwanted tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("span.conf").remove()
  $(".box, .view, .conf").contents().unwrap();
})
```

Comment: Thank you Dmirty. `$obj.contents().unwrap();` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Given there's so many elements to traverse and amend, you're probably best to copy the `.col-md-6` elements out of that structure and build your own parents around them, something like this:

```
var $holder = $('#holder');
var $content = $holder.find('.col-md-6');
$holder.empty().append($content);
$content.wrapAll('<div class="demoContainer container-fluid"><div class="row"></div></div>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9pw5cg6/5/)

Alternatively, assuming that you want to copy the reduced HTML structure for each `.box` element, you just need to loop over them:

```
var $holder = $('#holder');
$holder.find('.box').each(function() {
    var $content = $(this).find('.col-md-6');
    $holder.append($content);
    $content.wrapAll('<div class="demoContainer container-fluid"><div class="row"></div></div>');
});
$holder.find('.box').remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9pw5cg6/6/)

Comment: **col-md-6** and  **container-fluid** may vary. What do I do in this situation?